# Set rotation of QGraphicsItem by dragging a child element

Tags: python, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem, pyside2

I have a `QGraphicsItem` box with a child ellipse (a `QGraphicsEllipseItem`):

[image: Rotating parent by dragging child node]

I want to let the user drag the ellipse around to set the rotation of the box. The box should be rotated to point towards the center of the ellipse whenever the ellipse is dragged, regardless of the circle's position (i.e. it can be moved further from or closer to the mirror; it doesn't matter). To do this, I set up the ellipse's `itemChange` event to grab the `ItemPositionChange` type and then emit a signal with the updated position, which is caught by the parent and used to set the parent's rotation:

```
class Mirror(QGraphicsSvgItem):    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Add rotation node.
        self.node = Node(self.width, self.height / 2, parent=self)
        self.node.setPos(30, 0)
        self.node.POSITION_CHANGE.connect(self.set_angle_from_node)

    def set_angle_from_node(self, node, position):
        self.setRotation(math.degrees(math.atan2(position.y(), position.x())))


class Node(QGraphicsEllipseItem, QObject):
    RADIUS = 4
    POSITION_CHANGE = Signal(QGraphicsEllipseItem, QPointF)

    def __init__(self, origin_x, origin_y, **kwargs):
        # Call parent constructors separately due to a segmentation fault (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-800)
        QGraphicsEllipseItem.__init__(self, origin_x - self.RADIUS, origin_y - self.RADIUS,
                                      self.RADIUS * 2, self.RADIUS * 2, **kwargs)
        QObject.__init__(self)

        self.setFlag(self.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setFlag(self.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)
        self.setFlag(self.ItemIsSelectable)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == self.ItemPositionChange:
            self.POSITION_CHANGE.emit(self, value)

        return super().itemChange(change, value)
```

(Note that the `Node` class inherits from `QObject` in order to use `Signal` capabilities.)

The problem I seem to have is that by setting the parent's angle with `setRotation`, I implicitly rotate the ellipse's coordinate system as well. In addition to being moved in the local coordinate system by the drag, the ellipse's coordinate system is also rotated by the parent box. This means the child ellipse moves further than the mouse drags it:

[image: Parent rotates further than child]

(The arrow shows the approximate cursor drag path from the initial click. Ideally, the ellipse would stay under the cursor when dragged.)

I could fix this by decoupling the coordinate systems by making the ellipse a completely separate scene object, not a child of the left object, but I want to maintain this hierarchy for other reasons such as the ability to reposition the "box + ellipse" system by dragging the box.

To try to fix this, I figured out that the return value from the `itemChange` method of the ellipse is used to update the position of the ellipse, so I therefore tried emitting the real new ellipse coordinates to the parent but overriding the y-value to 0 for the returned value, so it was always right of the right side of the box as in the first diagram:

```
def itemChange(self, change, value):
    if change == self.ItemPositionChange:
        self.POSITION_CHANGE.emit(self, value)
        # Override coordinate used to update this ellipse's position
        value.setY(0)

    return super().itemChange(change, value)
```

However, this didn't fix the problem either; the extra rotation is still there and seems even more chaotic. I am not sure why that didn't help, but I am also not sure if there isn't a better way to do this that I am missing. Does anyone have a good idea how to get this to work?

Comment: A child item has a coordinate system that is based on the parent, so when you calculate the angle and set the rotation in the parent will also rotate the child but as you are holding it with the mouse the system will try to compensate by generating oscillations the angle of rotation since it is a coupled system. The best thing is that everyone has their coordinate system. I do not understand why you want a child item, they should be sibling items

Comment: @eyllanesc, you make a good point. It will increase complexity in my code slightly to support separate items as part of the same logical "unit", but since it decouples the coordinates I guess that's a reasonable compromise. Thanks.